# client-side file caching

Tags: caching

If I understand correctly, a broswer caches images, JS files, etc. based on the file name. So there's a danger that if one such file is updated (on the server), the browser will use the cached copy instead.

A workaround for this problem is to rename all files (as part of the build), such that the file name includes an MD5 hash of it's contents, e.g.

```
foo.js -> foo_AS577688BC87654.js
me.png -> me_32126A88BC3456BB.png
```

However, in addition to renaming the files themselves, all references to these files must be changed. For exmaple a tag such as `<img src="me.png"/>` should be changed to `<img src="me_32126A88BC3456BB.png"/>`.

Obviously this can get pretty complicated, particularly when you consider that references to these files may be dynamically created within server-side code.

Of course, one solution is to completely disable caching on the browser (and any caches between the server and the browser) using HTTP headers. However, having no caching will create it's own set of problems.

Is there a better solution?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Is this really an issue?  Modern browsers will check at least once per session, if not every page refresh, to see if an image or js or other referenced file is updated by adding a if-modified-since header in their request.  If the file is not modified, the web server will return 304 and the browser will use the cached file.

Comment: I have noticed a case where Safari didn't update the cache despite the user using F5. Unfortunately I didn't do an in depth review since it was over the phone and only the client was viewing it at that time so I had the user clear their browser cache and then Safari grabbed the new version.

Comment: *based on the file name* - not quite, see ETags: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag What you would do, is use your hash as the resource's ETag.

Comment: GrandmasterB : yes, it is really an issue. Modern browsers will hopefully not check if a file has been modified or not if the server sends a header with a far-future expire date. This allows to reach high performance levels.
So there is a need to invalidate the cache sometimes, if you're using modern recommended techniques to effectively use the browser's cache.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best solution seems to be to version filenames by appending the last-modified time.

You can do it this way: add a rewrite rule to your Apache configuration, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+)\.(js|css|jpg|png|gif)$ $1.$3
```

This will redirect any "versioned" URL to the "normal" one. The idea is to keep your filenames the same, but to benefit from cache. The solution to append a parameter to the URL will not be optimal with some proxies that don't cache URLs with parameters.

Then, instead of writing:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

Just call a PHP function:

```
<img src="<?php versionFile('image.png'); ?>" />
```

With versionFile() looking like this:

```
function versionFile($file){
    $path = pathinfo($file);
    $ver = '.'.filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file).'.';
    echo $path['dirname'].'/'.str_replace('.', $ver, $path['basename']);
}
```

And that's it! The browser will ask for image.123456789.png, Apache will redirect this to image.png, so you will benefit from cache in all cases and won't have any out-of-date issue, while not having to bother with filename versioning.

You can see a detailed explanation of this technique here: http://particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/

Comment: This is by far the best solution here.

Comment: Thanks ! :-) But the author from particletree deserves all the credit.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just add a querystring "version" number and update the version each time?

foo.js -> foo.js?version=5

There still is a bit of work during the build to update the version numbers but filenames don't need to change.

Comment: Query strings are a bad idea if you care about caching because most proxy servers do not cache resources with a '?' in their URL.  See http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html.

Comment: Paul - I think that the recommendations on that page are incomplete. Section 13.9 of RFC 2616 (the HTTP 1.1 spec) seems to imply that query strings can be cacheable if there's an explicit Expires header, so perhaps using a querystring is fine. But, this doesn't mean that all caches will honor this, so I'd probably stick with modifying the filenames myself.

Answer (score 6):

Renaming your resources is the way to go, although we use a build number and embed that in to the file name instead of an MD5 hash

```
foo.js -> foo.123.js
```

as it means that all your resources can be renamed in a deterministic fashion and resolved at runtime.

We then use custom controls to generate links to resources at on page load based upon the build number which is stored in an app setting.

Answer (score 3):

We followed a similar pattern to PJP, using Rails and Nginx.

We wanted user avatar images to be browser cached, but on an avatar's change we needed the cache to be invalidated ASAP.

We added a method to the avatar model to append a timestamp to the file name:

```
return "/images/#{sourcedir}/#{user.login}-#{self.updated_at.to_s(:flat_string)}.png"
```

In all places in the code where avatars were used, we referenced this method rather than an URL. In the Nginx configuration, we added this rewrite:

```
rewrite "^/images/avatars/(.+)-[\d]{12}.png"    /images/avatars/$1.png;
rewrite "^/images/small-avatars/(.+)-[\d]{12}.png"      /images/small-avatars/$1.png;
```

This meant if a file changed, its URL in the HTML changed, so the user's browser made a new request for the file. When the request reached Nginx, it got rewritten to the simple name of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using caching by ETags in this situation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag. You can then use the hash as the etag. A request will still be submitted for each resource, but the browser will only download items that have changed since last download.

Read up on your web server / platform docs on how to use etags properly, most decent platforms have built-in support.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers check the if-modified-since header whenever a cacheable resource is in a HTTP request. However, not all browsers support the if-modified-since header.

There are three ways to "force" the browser to load a cached resource.

**Option 1** Create a query string with a version#. `src="script.js?ver=21"`. The downside is many proxy servers wont cache a resource with query strings. It also requires site-wide updating for changes.

**Option 2** Create a naming system for your files `src="script083010.js"`. However the downside to option 1 is that this as well requires site-wide updates whenever a file changes.

**Option 3** Perhaps the most elegant solution, simply set up the caching headers: last-modified and expires in your server. The main downside to this is users may have to recache resources because they expired yet never changed. Additionally, the last-modified header does not work well when content is being served from multiple servers.

Here a few resources to check out: [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) [Google](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) [AskApache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html)

Comment: Lol read your answer after mine, almost exactly the same. +1 for hivemind.

Answer (score 2):

This is really only an issue if your web server sets a far-future "Expires" header (setting something like `ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"` in your Apache config). Otherwise, a browser will make a conditional GET, based on the modified time and/or the Etag. You can verify what is happening on your site by using a web proxy or an extension like Firebug (on the Net panel). Your question doesn't mention how your web server is configured, and what headers it is sending with static files.

If you're not setting a far-future Expires header, there's nothing special you need to do. Your web server will usually handle conditional GETs for static files based on last modified time just fine. If you are setting a far-future Expires header then yes, you need to add some sort of version to the file name like your question and the other answers have mentioned already.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been thinking about this for a site I support where it would be a big job to change all references. I have two ideas:

1.
Set distant cache expiry headers and apply the changes you suggest for the most commonly downloaded files. For other files set the headers so they expire after a very short time - eg. 10 minutes. Then if you have a 10 minute downtime when updating the application, caches will be refreshed by the time users go to the site. General site navigation should be improved as the files will only need downloading every 10 minutes not every click.

2.
Each time a new version of the application is deployed to a different context that contains the version number. eg. www.site.com/app_2_6_0/ I'm not really sure about this as users bookmarks would be broken on each update.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a combination of solutions works best:

1. Setting cache expiry dates for each type of resource (image, page, etc) appropreatly for that resource, for example:

   - Your static "About", "Contact" etc pages probably arn't going to change more than a few time a year, so you could easily put a cache time of a month on these pages.
   - Images used in these pages could have eternal cache times, as you are more likey to replace an image then to change one.
   - Avatar images might have an expiry time of a day.
2. Some resources need modified dates in their names. For example avatars, generated images, and the like.
3. Some things should never be caches, new pages, user content etc. In these cases you should cache on the server, but never on the client side.

In the end you need to carfully consider each type of resource to determine what cache time to instruct the browser to use, and always be conservitive if you are unsure. You can increase the time later, but it's much more pain to uncache something.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the approach taken by the grails "uiperformance" plugin, which you can find [here](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ui-performance). It does a lot of the things you mention, but automates them (set expiry time to a long time, then increments version numbers when files change).

So if you're using grails, you get this stuff for free. If you are not - maybe you can borrow the techniques employed.

Also - borrowed form the ui-performance page, - read the following [14 rules](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rules.php).

Answer (score 1):

ETags seemingly provide a solution for this...

As per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#fileetag, we can set the browser to generate ETags on file-size (instead of time/inode/etc). This generation should be constant across multiple server deployments.

Just enable it in (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

```
FileETag Size
```

& you should be good!

That way, you can simply reference your images as `<img src='/path/to/foo.png' />` and still use all the goodness of HTTP caching.